# How to add choice-items to a menu-choice widget through code?

Tags: widget

Looking up information from an Active Directory, I want to populate a form.  Generally that works fine with `editable-field`s, since all one has to do is to add the value, which Emacs has a function for (`(widget-value-set)`).  However, for one element I will need to use a drop-down field to only choose one of potentially more options, but I appear to fail to understand how to add items to a `menu-choice` widget.

My constant helper for building forms is the [Emacs widget library](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html).  However, even the programming example under 3 is not revealing this as the example simply hard-coded them.

My current mock-up for testing this outside the actual environment looks like the following:

```lisp
(let ((sBuffer "*Test*")
      (lItems  (list '(item :tag "Test 1" :value 1)
                     '(item :tag "Test 2" :value 2))))
  (switch-to-buffer sBuffer)
  (make-local-variable 'wADgroup)
  
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (erase-buffer))
  (remove-overlays)

  (setq wButton      (widget-create 'push-button
                                    :notify (lambda (widget &rest ignore)
                                              (widget-put wADgroup :children lItems)
                                              ;;(widget-value-set wADgroup 1)
                                              (widget-setup))
                                    "Click me!"))
  (widget-insert "\n\n")
  (setq wADgroup     (widget-create 'menu-choice
                                    :tag "- AD group "
                                    :value 1
                                    :notify (lambda (widget &rest ignore))))
  
  (use-local-map widget-keymap)
  (widget-setup))
```

Pressing the button in the above shall add the items.

Is there a way to dynamically add items to an existing `menu-choice` widget in hindsight or does it need to be deleted and re-created?  I tried to add a list for `:children`, but that did not seem to have an effect and I am not sure how to add "loose" arguments when using `widget-create` (for any ordinary list I would use `(append)`, of course).  Even if the widget would need to be re-created, I still fail to understand how to programmatically add the items.

I'm using Emacs 28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure that the `:children` of a widget are the visible children of the widget. The `choice` widget only displays currently selected widget, so modifying `:children` is not what you want. Modify the `:args` list instead.

Don’t forget that you can use `widget-browse-at` to open a debug window that shows you all the properties of the widget under the point.

Comment: Awesome!  That did it.  And thanks for the additional command.  That makes troubleshooting widgets tremendously easier in the future.  Thank you very much!